# Impact of not using .row class inside Bootstrap 3 grid structure

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I hired someone to implement the design of a website. He is using bootstrap 3 (which I've used before in some projects) and it surprised me that he is avoiding the use of .row class in every the grid and subgrid built (he is using clearfix to make the rows). He's code looks something like this...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <ul>
            <li><a>item 1</a></li>
            <li><a>item 2</a></li>
            <li><a>item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 pull-right">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>Menu item 1</li>
            <li class="shop">Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

From what I've read, .row class is used to

1. "create horizontal groups of columns." [source](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)
2. "row nullifies the padding set by the container element by using a negative margin value of -15px on both the left and right sides." [source](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstrap-grid-system/)

What is the impact of not using this class inside the grid structure? should I make sure he uses .row class?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the bootstrap docs

> Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or
>   .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

You are also correct in that `.row` clears the gutters from the container which has a padding of `15px` left and right.

```
.container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Therefore, I personally would err on the side of caution and follow the requirements set out by bootstrap. In the future, the framework could change and a strong reliance could be created upon the row class and since that is missing from your code, it would require reworking it to update versions... or optionally, you could choose to implement responsive selectors such as `.col-xs-` which could over or underlap the 12 column grid format.